# How to create a chat function (like facebook or gmail) in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, chat

I have searched through stackoverflow on the key words of "facebook chat in asp.net", just come out of some profounded suggestions. But I have some detail questions need to be cleared.

1. Do people use database to store each message? Do they have to be
   saved in database?
2. Do people use session to send/receive message?
3. Is jQuery useful here?

Please give me a direction on how to develop chat function in asp.net

Comment: at the top of this page is a link marked "chat", which links to a chat written in ASP.NET (MVC). For the record, it uses SQL Server (although any RDBMS or NOSQL would suffice), ajax polling via jQuery (with some HTML5 hooks for efficiency), and lots of jQuery for the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, most likely. Assuming they need to be saved somewhere the best answer is usually a database. What kind, SQL or NOSQL depends on scale and the skill set of the developers.
2. There are lots of techniques for fetching new messages. Some Google keywords might be "long polling", ajax, etc.
3. jQuery is a JavaScript library for handling common client side scripting tasks. You can do without, but if you know jQuery or some other JavaScript library it will save you from a lot of coding. Regardless if you are writing a chat system or something else.

As a side note. Don't look at the implementation of gmail or facebook. There are lots of descriptions out there on how they build their stuff. They build for immense scale. You don't. They use a nail gun because they need too, you just need a hammer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think the facebook or gmail chat is pretty cool cause they displayed and popout when new message comes. I'm familiar with jQuery, just don't know how to use it here, I mean to develop  chat function. The main concern is, I want to know the back end process of chat function. Do you know it?